# Export c++ functions inside a C# Application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, export, managed-code

Greetings,
I am sorry for bothering, I'll show the question:

I am trying to export some functions written in c++ in a DLL in order to import them in a C# Application running on Visual Studio.
I make the export as reported in the following code,

tobeexported.h:

```
namespace SOMENAMESPACE
{
                class __declspec(dllexport) SOMECLASS
                {
                               public: 
                               SOMETYPE func(param A,char b[tot]);

                };
}
```

tobeexported.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tobeexported.h"
...


using namespace SOMENAMESPACE;

SOMETYPE SOMECLASS:: func(param A,char b[tot])
                {
                               ...some stuff inside...
                }
```

The dll is righly created and the code is already CLR-managed(looked with a disassembling software(reflector)) and contains the exported functions
 then I "Add the Reference" in my c# application and the dll is found, but when
I open it with the object browser it is completely empty, neither class, nor object has been exported and ready to be used

can you help me please?
thanks
best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using managed C++ to compile your DLL? Then you just have to add a ref to the class like this:

```
namespace SOMENAMESPACE
{
                public ref class SOMECLASS
                {
                               public: 
                               SOMETYPE func(param A,char b[tot]);

                };
}
```

After successful compilation and referencing in the other project, the class should be visible. Exporting native C++ is not really portable, each compiler produces different results and is tedious to bind from within C#...

EDIT: added public access modifier to ref class...

Comment: Thanks for answer,
I am using managed c++ (in Visual Studio the project that contains c++ code is a “class library”) but even with “ref” command instead of export it works, the given result is completely the same.
[The operation of importing is possible even because I previously imported a c++ dll; I created my new dll really similar to the working one but nothing good happens^^]
 
Thanks again

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to tell you to add also public, `public ref class ...`. I hope then that it will work fine. In the .NET reflector the visibility is probably private or internal am I right?